# Como mostrar un poligono en python?

Tags: python, geolocalización

Estoy tratando de crear un poligono y con este mismo saber si las coordenadas que ingreso estan dentro del poligono, al intentar ejecutar me manda el siguiente error

> RGBA values should be within 0-1 range

ya tengo muchas de las cosas solo me queda proyectar el poligono para saber si es correcto

Este es mi codigo

```
import geopandas as gpd
import pymongo
import json
import numpy as np
import subprocess
import mpl_toolkits
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
# from VALID import OKI, OK, ns
from turtle import Turtle
from pymongo import MongoClient

#aqui consultamos a la db para que nos traiga los puntos
client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db = client.siete.geozonas
res = db.find({'GeoName': "XXXXXXXX"}, {'points': '1', '_id': 0})

for zone in res:
    point_one = zone['points'][0][0]
    point_two = zone['points'][0][1]
    point_three = zone['points'][0][2]
    point_four = zone['points'][0][3]
    point_five = zone['points'][0][4]

#aqui asingamos los valores para poder crear el poligono

coordenadas_1 = [point_one['x'], point_one['y']]
coordenadas_2 = [point_two['x'], point_two['y']]
coordenadas_3 = [point_three['x'], point_three['y']]
coordenadas_4 = [point_four['x'], point_four['y']]
coordenadas_5 = [point_five['x'], point_five['y']]

poly = Polygon([coordenadas_1, coordenadas_2, coordenadas_3, coordenadas_4, coordenadas_5])
x,y = poly.exterior.xy
plt.scatter(31.6951046,-106.318077,marker='+', linewidths=1, c="r", s=90)
plt.plot(x, y, color='y', alpha=2, linewidth=2, solid_capstyle='round', zorder=2) 
plt.show() #aqui es donde me muestra el error 

def punto_en_poligono(x, y, poligono):
    i = 0
    j = len(poligono) - 1
    salida = False
    for i in range(len(poligono)):
        if (poligono[i][1] < y and poligono[j][1] >= y) or (poligono[j][1] < y and poligono[i][1] >= y):
            if poligono[i][0] + (y - poligono[i][1]) / (poligono[j][1] - poligono[i][1]) * (poligono[j][0] - poligono[i][0]) < x:
                salida = not salida
        j = i
    return salida
```

realmente es un algo dificil de crear... bueno al menos para mi

Comment: No veo la relación entre la pregunta y el error.

Comment: ¿Ya comprobaste que los valores para el R, G, B y Alpha sean entre 0 y 1?

Comment: Si, los colores que uso con red 'r' y 'y'

Comment: ¿Y ese alpha=2 que veo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El primer error que tienes está en el **alpha**, este parámetros en términos simples indica el porcentaje de transparencia y va desde 0 hasta 1, si lo modificas el script funciona normalmente.

```
plt.plot(x, y, color='y', alpha=1, linewidth=2, solid_capstyle='round', zorder=2)
```

Por otra parte, no es necesario que definas tu propia función para saber si un punto está dentro del polígono, la librería **shapely** ya tiene esta funcionalidad.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
from shapely.geometry import Polygon, Point

#aqui asingamos los valores para poder crear el poligono
coordenadas_1 = (0, 2)
coordenadas_2 = (1, 0)
coordenadas_3 = (3, 0)
coordenadas_4 = (4, 2)
coordenadas_5 = (2, 3)

# definimos el poligono
poly = Polygon([coordenadas_1, coordenadas_2, coordenadas_3, coordenadas_4, coordenadas_5])

# definimos un punto cualquiera
point = Point((2, 1))

# comprobamos si está dentro del poligono
poly.contains(point):
```

Y ya con esto puedes graficar con normalidad

```
x, y = poly.exterior.xy
plt.scatter(point.x, point.y, marker='+', linewidths=1, c="r", s=90)
# alpha dentro de 0 y 1
plt.plot(x, y, color='y', alpha=0.9, linewidth=2, solid_capstyle='round', zorder=2) 
plt.show()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]